# Laravel Eloquent eager loading, few columns related to one table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have the Models structure from database like this:

```
class Player extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'players';

}
```

related to Players (this table always have to have 5 fixed positions):

```
class FormationPositions
{
    protected $table = 'formation_position';

    public function fpos1()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'fpos_1');
    }

    public function fpos2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'fpos_2');
    }

    public function fpos3()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'fpos_3');
    }

    public function fpos4()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'fpos_4');
    }

    public function fpos5()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'fpos_5');
    }

}
```

when I try to eager load `FormationPositions` table like this:

`FormationPositions::with(['fpos1', 'fpos2', 'fpos3', 'fpos4', 'fpos5'])`

then I got 5 queries to database to load these object, maybe there is some way to combine this structure into one query with Elequent eager way  `SELECT * FROM table where id IN (?)` and load data to that objects with one query?

Comment: You can just add: `protected $with = ['fpos1', 'fpos2', 'fpos3', 'fpos4', 'fpos5'];` in your player model to have it load always :)

Comment: and you will get 5 querys to database not 1

Comment: Is it possible you could share a little bit more of your schema? It seems to me like this would be a good case for refactoring the structure of your data.